# Convert Charset in ASP.NET for only certain fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, character-encoding

> EDIT FOR FUTURE VIEWERS - Fixed by changing character set to CP1252 in
>   php.ini

So recently I took on the task of redoing an old website we created a number of years ago, updating it to be faster, more efficient and, most importantly, not on the WordPress back end.

We are almost done, but I have run into a snag. The old database was done in the `CP1252` encoding format and when updating the code, we have converted to the `UTF-8` standard. This has naturally caused a number of database entries to be formatted improperly and, with 42,000+ entries in one table alone, it's not super easy to re-enter all the data.

I worked with a developer to create a simple PHP script that loads if an entry's 'id' is below a certain number to convert the old data to `UTF-8` upon display.

Here's an example as it pulls an obituary:

```php
function convert_charset($input){
  return iconv('CP1252', 'UTF-8', $input);
}

…

if ($row["id"] > "42362") {
  return $row["obituary"];
}
else {
  return stripslashes(convert_charset($row["obituary"]));
}
```

This works perfectly. But now I have to convert the mobile site (of course the project lead doesn't want to do a responsive site. OF COURSE HE DOESN'T THAT WOULD MAKE TOO MUCH SENSE) and it's written in ASP.NET, which I have no experience working with, and don't know where to even start.

It is pulling the information as such:

```cs
HTML += "<a href='http://twitter.com/share?text=Obituary for " + firstName + "'>";
```

Can I just get it to load the PHP queries in the header and copy how I have been doing it in PHP into ASP.NET? Being that the information is now separated, is there a way I can convert after a certain point if I can't?

Comment: Hi, Darien, welcome to Stack Overflow. My immediate question upon reading this is why you aren't writing the transcoded data back to the database? If you did that, then it's a one time resolution, and you won't need to dynamically evaluate and transcode the content each and every time you load the page.

Comment: As far as migrating this code to ASP.NET, obviously the syntax is going to be a bit different. Since you specify ASPX, I am assuming you're using ASP.NET Web Forms? Do you have a sample of where you're attempting to implement this in ASP.NET? And what specific errors you're running into? That will help provide more focused guidance.

Comment: I have attempted the transcoding the following way:

```php
/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "CP1252"); 
```

Still inputs as UTF-8. I have searched my code for any reference to UTF-8 with no success.

I have no attempted to convert the charset in ASP.Net as it's been over 13 years since I last touched ASP.net so even the first steps allude me.

Comment: After over-analyzing the situation, I changed the encoding in the php.ini file and everything is working properly now.

Here I was thinking it was code that had to do it but a simple swap and everything works